# React Testing Library works on HTML elements but not with React components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-testing, user-event

Basically, I'm trying to test a component that have a select.

When trying to test the component, the test fails by returning the default value instead of the changed value.

But when I take the HTML of the rendered component (from screen.debug()) it works.

The component:

```
export function SelectFile({
  fileList,
  handleChange,
  selected,
}) {
  return (
    <select
      className="bg-slate-600 rounded w-auto"
      onChange={onChange}
      value={selected}
    >
      <option value="">Select an option</option>
      <TodayOptions />
      <AllOptions />
    </select>
  );

  function AllOptions() {
    return (
      <>
        {Object.entries(groups).map(([key, value]) => {
          return (
            <optgroup key={key} label={key.toLocaleUpperCase()}>
              {[...value].sort(sortByDateFromLogs).map((item) => (
                <option key={item} value={item}>
                  {item}
                </option>
              ))}
            </optgroup>
          );
        })}
      </>
    );
  }

  function TodayOptions() {
    const todayFiles = Object.values(groups)
      .map((group) => {
        const today = new Date().toLocaleDateString().replace(/\//g, '-');
        return group.filter((file) => file.includes(today));
      })
      .flat();

    if (todayFiles.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <optgroup label="Today">
        {todayFiles.map((item) => (
          <option key={item}>{item}</option>
        ))}
      </optgroup>
    );
  }
}
```

The original test:

```
 it('should change option', () => {
    render(
      <SelectFile
        fileList={fileList}
        handleChange={handleChange}
        selected=""
      />,
    );

    const selectElement = screen.getByDisplayValue('Select an option');
    const allOptions = screen.getAllByRole('option');

    const optionSelected = fileList.adonis[1];

    expect(selectElement).toHaveValue('');

    act(() => {
      userEvent.selectOptions(selectElement, optionSelected);
    });

    expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(selectElement).toHaveValue(optionSelected); // returns "" (default value)
    expect((allOptions[0] as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBe(false);
    expect((allOptions[1] as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBe(true);
    expect((allOptions[2] as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBe(false);
    expect((allOptions[3] as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBe(false);
    expect((allOptions[4] as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBe(false);
  });
```

And the modified test with the rendered html:

```
 it('should change option', () => {
    render(
      <div>
        <div className="flex mr-10">
          <h3 className="text-lg font-bold mr-4">Select a file</h3>
          <select className="bg-slate-600 rounded w-auto">
            <option value="">Select an option</option>
            <optgroup label="ADONIS">
              <option value="adonis-03-02-2022.json">
                adonis-03-02-2022.json
              </option>
              <option value="adonis-02-02-2022.json">
                adonis-02-02-2022.json
              </option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="ERRORS">
              <option value="http_errors-03-03-2022.log">
                http_errors-03-03-2022.log
              </option>
              <option value="http_errors-04-02-2022.log">
                http_errors-04-02-2022.log
              </option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>,
    );

    const selectElement = screen.getByDisplayValue('Select an option');
    const allOptions = screen.getAllByRole('option');

    const optionSelected = fileList.adonis[1];

    expect(selectElement).toHaveValue('');

    act(() => {
      userEvent.selectOptions(selectElement, optionSelected);
    });

    expect(selectElement).toHaveValue(optionSelected); // this returns the optionSelected value
    expect((allOptions[0] as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBe(false);
    expect((allOptions[1] as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBe(true);
    expect((allOptions[2] as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBe(false);
    expect((allOptions[3] as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBe(false);
    expect((allOptions[4] as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBe(false);
  });
```

Considering it works with the modified test, I can't make it why it doesn't on the original.
I've considered it was due to the optgroup, but it doesn't seems the case, so now I'm at a loss as to why.

---

Edit: the final version of the test:

```
  it('should change option', () => {
    const mockHandleChange = handleChange.mockImplementation(
      (cb) => (e) => cb(e.target.value),
    );

    render(
      <SelectWrapper fileList={fileList} handleChange={mockHandleChange} />,
    );

    const selectElement = screen.getByDisplayValue('Select an option');

    const optionSelected = fileList.adonis[1];

    expect(selectElement).toHaveValue('');

    act(() => {
      userEvent.selectOptions(selectElement, optionSelected);
    });

    expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2); // 1 for cb wrapper, 1 for select
    expect(selectElement).toHaveValue(optionSelected);
  });
});

const SelectWrapper = ({ handleChange, fileList }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('');

  const mockHandleChange = handleChange(setSelected);

  return (
    <SelectFile
      fileList={fileList}
      handleChange={mockHandleChange}
      selected={selected}
    />
  );
};
```

I've created a wrapper to make it like you would use in another component, wrapped the mock function and now it changes the value and you have access to the mock.

Comment: What fails in the original test? Everything?

Comment: @BenSmith it returns an empty value (the default option)
thank you, I've edited the question.

Comment: Did you try using https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom toHaveValue (https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavevalue) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in your test you are rendering only the `Select` (which is a controlled component : it receives from its parent the current value and a `onChange` callback), with a fixed `selected` props, you cannot expect the selected option to change when you trigger a change event on the select. You can only expect that the `onChange` callback has been called (like you do).

For this kind of component, you need to test that the `selected` props is respected (the selected option is the good one), and that the provided callback is called when the user chooses a new option (you ahve done this part).

You need to add a test with an existing option as `selected` props (not empty string), then check that the `selected` option is the right one. I suggest you use https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavevalue from https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom.

Comment: I believe I'm doing that already: `expect(selectElement).toHaveValue(optionSelected)` but it returns `''`, the default value

Comment: Indeed, but since you render only the child component, with selected="", your select will never have another value.

Comment: Unlike an uncontrolled select